# Delete key and its values in a double nested dictionary in O(1) without loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, graph, nested

I'm learning about graph data structures in python, and one of the questions was based on both undirected & directed graphs. It challenges you to delete a vertex in O(deg(v)) time, and delete an edge in O(1) time. I've managed to delete the vertex, but after deleting the vertex the edges from/to that vertex need to be deleted. the delete_edge fxn is what I'm having an issue with, because this is a nested dictionary, i'm finding it hard to delete the edge.

Here's the Undirected Original Graph:

```
 C {A: (A,C,2), B: (B,C,5), E: (C,E,7), D: (C,D,6)}
 A {B: (A,B,1), C: (A,C,2), E: (A,E,4), D: (A,D,3)}
 B {A: (A,B,1), C: (B,C,5)}
 E {A: (A,E,4), C: (C,E,7)}
 D {A: (A,D,3), C: (C,D,6)}
```

This is the fxn to find all incident edges for a given vertex:

```
def incident_edges(self, v, outgoing=True):   
#Return all (outgoing) edges incident to vertex v in the graph.
#If graph is directed, optional parameter used to request incoming edges.

self._validate_vertex(v)
adj = self._outgoing if outgoing else self._incoming
for edge in adj[v].values():
  yield edge
```

This is the fxn i wrote to remove a vertex in O(deg(v)) time:

```
def remove_vertex(self, v):
"""Remove the vertex v and all its incident edges,
and return the vertex been removed.
Parameter v is an instance of Vertex
Algorithm should run in O(deg(v)) time
"""

 for i in self.incident_edges(v):
   self.remove_edge(i)

 del self._outgoing[v]

 return v
```

This is how far I got with the remove_edge fxn:

```
def remove_edge(self, e):
"""remove the edge e from the adjacency map for each
incident vertex, and return the edge removed.
Parameter e is an instance of Edge
Algorithm should run in O(1) time.
""" 
   list(list(self._outgoing.values())[list(self._outgoing.values())[list(self._outgoing.values()).index(e)]])
```

But it doesn't work! I can't seem to be able to navigate in a nested dict in O(1). Not sure what to do! Anyone with more experience please help!

Current Output:

```
    Undirected Original Graph:
    D {A: (A,D,3), C: (C,D,6)}
    C {A: (A,C,2), B: (B,C,5), D: (C,D,6), E: (C,E,7)}
    B {A: (A,B,1), C: (B,C,5)}
    A {B: (A,B,1), C: (A,C,2), D: (A,D,3), E: (A,E,4)}
    E {A: (A,E,4), C: (C,E,7)}

    Number of vertices is 5
    Number of edges is 7

    Undirected Graph After deleting Vertex 'D':
    (which consequently deletes its incident edges)
    C {A: (A,C,2), B: (B,C,5), D: (C,D,6), E: (C,E,7)}
    B {A: (A,B,1), C: (B,C,5)}
    A {B: (A,B,1), C: (A,C,2), D: (A,D,3), E: (A,E,4)}
    E {A: (A,E,4), C: (C,E,7)}

    Number of vertices is 4
    Number of edges is 6
```

Expected Output:

```
    Undirected Original Graph:
    D {A: (A,D,3), C: (C,D,6)}
    C {A: (A,C,2), B: (B,C,5), D: (C,D,6), E: (C,E,7)}
    B {A: (A,B,1), C: (B,C,5)}
    A {B: (A,B,1), C: (A,C,2), D: (A,D,3), E: (A,E,4)}
    E {A: (A,E,4), C: (C,E,7)}

    Number of vertices is 5
    Number of edges is 7

    Undirected Graph After deleting Vertex 'D':
    (which consequently deletes its incident edges)
    C {A: (A,C,2), B: (B,C,5), E: (C,E,7)}
    B {A: (A,B,1), C: (B,C,5)}
    A {B: (A,B,1), C: (A,C,2), E: (A,E,4)}
    E {A: (A,E,4), C: (C,E,7)}

    Number of vertices is 4
    Number of edges is 6
```

Thanks!

PS: if there's somethings missing that you might need for more reference, please let me know! Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post a snap of the output you're currently generating and a snap of expected output.?

Comment: Hi @AshSharma, I've added it to my post! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your Graph representation `Adjacency List` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) to an `Adjacency matrix` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) ?

It seems to me far more suitable in your use case because if you do so, you can delete a Node and its Edges in 2 operations which are "delete the row corresponding to your node" and "delete the column corresponding to your node". Which can be done in `O(1)`.

However, the conversion of an `Adjacency List` to an `Adjacency Matrix` is done in `O(|E|)` (where E is your set of edges) but I don't think that it is taken into account in your exercise.

Comment: Consider looking at the `Incidence Matrix` article too (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix).